# Site doesn't reload after button click

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I developed a view to save `Child`-objects. Everything works fine but to see my additional objects in the `<p:dataTable>` I always have to reload the site manually.

Below the code for the `<p:commandButton>` which sends the form-data to my controller class.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
   <p:commandButton value="Save"
     action="#{childController.doSaveChild}"
     oncomplete="PF('childAddDialog').hide()"
     update=":childForm"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I already tried to use `ajax="false"`, but it doesn't work.

What can I do to get the site reloaded after click on save-button?

**UPDATE:**

`<p:dataTable>` from my view.xhtml:

```
 <h:form id="childForm">
 <p:dataTable id="childTable" var="child"
  widgetVar="childTable" value="#{childController.children}"
  paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
  paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
  {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}
  {Exporters}"
  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50">

 <p:column headerText="Firstname"     
    filterBy="#{child.firstName}"     
    sortBy="#{child.firstName}" filterStyle="display:none">    
    <h:outputText value="#{child.firstName}"/>                  
 </p:column>                                             
 <p:column headerText="Lastname"          
    filterBy="#{child.lastName}"      
    sortBy="#{child.lastName}" 
    filterStyle="display:none">             
    <h:outputText value="#{child.lastName}"/>   
 </p:column>                                             
 <p:column headerText="Birthday"     
    filterBy="#{child.birthday}"     
    sortBy="#{child.birthday}" 
    filterStyle="display:none">       
    <h:outputText value="#{child.birthday}"/>             
 </p:column>
 </dataTable>
 </form>
```

Here the methods for providing the children for the view:

```
public Collection<Child> getChildren(){
    return children;
}

@PostConstruct
public void initList(){
    setChildren(childService.getAllChildren());
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get your workaround working. I would focus on the original problem.

Comment: what would be the original problem in your opinion? I just want to get the site reloaded automatically.

Comment: The proper solution would be to get update working. You need to post your dataTable xhtml and relevant backing bean code.

Comment: It all works fine, I just have to reload it manually then the dataTable is up-to-date. Above you can find my dataTable

Comment: Erm, it doesn't work fine. Perhaps you forgot to update the `children` property after saving and therefore it still shows the list as it was before you added a new child?

Comment: @BalusC i added my methods from the controller which should hold the children-list up-to-date

Comment: Java methods are not called by magic. They are called by logic. The only method of interest here is `doSaveChild()`. As long as your `doSaveChild()` method does not invoke e.g. `initList()`, then the `children` obviously won't be updated after you save the child.

Comment: solved my problem .. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xhtml-code from above is fine.

To get the site auto-updated it is necessary to load the list with all children again after the save-method in controller.

```
public void doSaveChild(){
   childService.saveChild(child);
   child = null;
   initNewChild();
   initList();  //this is needed to get up-to-date list in view
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `process="@this"` on your command button

Answer (score -1):

You could either do it via javascript:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save"
 action="#{childController.doSaveChild}" process="@form" update="@none" oncomplete="location.reload();"/>
```

or a return String in your action method:

```
public String doSaveChild(){
//your logic
return "/yourpage?faces-redirect=true"}
```